# MySQL: Find all customerIDs with multiple ID Values

Tags: mysql

I have the following table

```
customerID | fieldID | fieldValue
1          | 1       | 0
1          | 2       | 8
1          | 3       | Test
1          | 4       | Other Value
2          | 1       | 8
2          | 4       | Testvalue
```

I want all customerID which have e.g. the following values:

```
fieldID | fieldValue
1       | 0
2       | 8
```

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT customerID
FROM my_table
WHERE
(fieldID = 1 AND fieldValue = 0) AND
(fieldID = 2 AND fieldValue = 8)
GROUP BY customerID
```

Since I do not get a value, there is surely an error here. How should I proceed here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the query you actually want here:

```sql
SELECT customerID
FROM my_table
GROUP BY customerID
HAVING SUM(fieldID = 1 AND fieldValue = 2) > 0 AND
       SUM(fieldID = 0 AND fieldValue = 8) > 0;
```

Comment: I will give it a try right away. Thank you. Does OR also work if I want to check both values?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the AND between the parenthesis to OR

```
SELECT customerID
FROM my_table
WHERE
(fieldID = 1 AND fieldValue = 0) OR
(fieldID = 2 AND fieldValue = 8)
GROUP BY customerID;
```

Comment: I will give it a try right away. Thank you. Does OR also work if I want to check both values?

Comment: with OR as we have it either the 2 conditions in the first parenthesis must both be true or the 2 in the second. As a field cannot have 2 values at the same time the 2 sets of conditions will never both be true.